# Работа с текстом (обрезание слов)

Tags: php

```
$text= '123 тутсловодлиннее10символов 123'
```

Как проанализировать этот текст и вырезать из него слова длиннее 10 символов?...
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$text= '123 тутсловодлиннее10символов 123';
$words = explode(" ", $text);
foreach ($words as $key => $value) {
$words[$key] = substr($value,0,10);
}
$text = implode(" ", $words);
```

---

Только что протестировал, **для кириллицы работает некорректно. Нужно использовать [mb_substr](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-substr.php)**

Т.е. получаем код:

```
$text= '123 тутсловодлиннее10символов 123';
$words = explode(" ", $text);
foreach ($words as $key => $value) {
    $words[$key] = mb_substr($value,0,10,'utf8');
}
$text = implode(" ", $words);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = '123 тутсловодлиннее10символов 123';
echo preg_replace('/\S{10,}/', '', $text);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$text= '123 тутсловодлиннее10символов 123';
if(strlen($text > 10)){
   $s = substr($text, 10)
   str_replace($s, '', $text);
} else {
    echo 'в тексте меньше 10 символов';
```

вот так, правда я не так написал как было задано, но подтолкнул а там дальше сами в мануал учить штатные ф-и

Comment: substr($text,0,10); - вот аналог) :<

Comment: ну вот, вы лучше меня знаете функции штатные, клаву в руки и кодить-кодить! я честно говоря давно на php не писал, так что такие мелочи по забывал уже

Comment: попытки завершились неудачей

Comment: а что именно? я дал вам все функции, и да же алгоритм, проверяете что бы было больше 10 символов(strlen) , достаете 10 символов(substr), вырезаете их с текста(str_replace)